# How can I bind a c#.net DataView (WPF) to a SQLite database?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am using the official System.Data.SQLite ADO.NET provider for my application, and I am trying to display the contents of a database in a WPF DataGrid. Currently I am able to select the data I need to display from the database, but I don't how to display that data on the datagrid.

I have search on the web, read blog posts, tutorials and guides, but to no avail. I am moving an application from a PHP system (using my local server) to a desktop application to be portable across systems. My current applications uses sqlite3 databases, and contains quite a few rows. This is why I would prefer to make sqlite work with c#, which is the desktop oriented language I am most comfortable with.

Comment: Here is a codeproject artical may help you [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just have to Bind the column to the name of the field in the db.

```
<local:AutoGenerateColumn Column="ItemStatusId"
           Binding="{Binding Path=ItemStatusId}" />
```

Here's a link to a pretty good tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DataGridAutoTemplate.aspx